# How to position a QLabel on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program where I need to create a `QLabel` by code, instead of drag and drop, but I'm having problems positioning the `QLabel` as I want, this is the code I have:

```
   if(ui->WorksList->currentItem()->text() == "Work1")
   {
       ui->InformationLabel->show();
       QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
       label->show();
       label->setText("Extraction");
       label->setMinimumWidth(100);
       int x = 2000;
       x = label->geometry().x();
       int y = 2000;
       y = label->geometry().y();   
   }
```

With this piece of code my `QLabel` do not move from the top left corner.

Thank you

Comment: Do you even know the direction of assignment? `QWidget::x` and `QWidget::y` are also `const` and return by value. So use `QWidget::move`.

Comment: With QWidget::move the label stopped appearing.

Comment: Do you have high enough resolution for those coordinates?

Comment: I've tried different ones already , 2000 or 20 is the same , it doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code doesn't move anything; as one of the comments said, you have to use the `move` method to move the label. If it doesn't show up, then it's either off screen or covered up by something else, or both. The coordinates for the `move` method are in the parent widget's coordinates, not the screen, and not the window. You've parented this `QLabel` to `this`, so the coordinates are relative to the top left corner of `this`, whatever that is.

Your code doesn't show what `this` is, nor any mention of how large the area of `this` is, so it's impossible for us to tell what coordinates might be reasonable.